# Android time and string

Tags: java, android, sql

in my app i recevie char sequence thats from sql something like this:

```
"{"1":{"from":"540","to":"1020"},"2":{"from":"540","to":"1020"},"3":{"from":"540","to":"1020"},"4":{"from":"540","to":"1020"},"5":{"from":"540","to":"1020"},"6":{"from":"540","to":"1020"},"7":{"from":"540","to":"1020"}}"
```

This is full week, day by day and minutes since midnight. I have idea how to use it but i don't know right now how to crop it on sense strings which should be looks like:

```
String monday_open = 540;
String monday_close = 1020;
```

and same to the end of the week
Maybe somebody know easy way to crop this sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this

```
"{"1":{"from":"540","to":"1020"},"2":{"from":"540","to":"1020"},"3":{"from":"540","to":"1020"},"4":{"from":"540","to":"1020"},"5":{"from":"540","to":"1020"},"6":{"from":"540","to":"1020"},"7":{"from":"540","to":"1020"}}"
```

is a json Text

my json String

```
{
"coord": {
    "lon": 51.42,
    "lat": 35.69
},
"weather": [
    {
        "id": 721,
        "main": "Haze",
        "description": "haze",
        "icon": "50n"
    }
],
"base": "cmc stations",
"main": {
    "temp": 298.45,
    "pressure": 1016,
    "humidity": 39,
    "temp_min": 298.15,
    "temp_max": 299.15
},
"wind": {
    "speed": 2.1,
    "deg": 240
},
"clouds": {
    "all": 40
},
"dt": 1439151053,
"sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 7032,
    "message": 0.0034,
    "country": "IR",
    "sunrise": 1439084924,
    "sunset": 1439134215
},
"id": 112931,
"name": "Tehran",
"cod": 200
}
```

and i parse it with method blew:

```
private void jsonRead(String file) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject root=new JSONObject(file);
    JSONArray jsonArray = root.optJSONArray("weather");
    JSONObject jo2=root.optJSONObject("main");
    for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        dama.setText(jsonObject.getString("description"));
    }
    rotobat.setText(jo2.getString("humidity"));
}
```

Comment: do you have same example?